# Is it possible for SQL Server to report an incorrect number of rows affected?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a utility which:

1. grabs sql commands from a flat text file
2. executes them sequentially against SQL Server located on the same machine
3. and reports an error if an UPDATE command affects ZERO ROWS (there should never be an update command in this file that doesn't affect a record, hence it being recorded as an error)

The utility also logs any failed commands.

**Yet the final data in the database seems to be wrong/stale, even though my utility is reporting no failed updates and no failed commands.**

I know the first and most obvious culprit is some kind of logic or runtime error in my programming of the utility itself, but I just need to know of it's THEORETICALLY possible for SQL Server to report that at least one row was affected and yet no apply the change.

If it helps, the utility always seems to correctly execute the same number of commands and the final stale/wrong data is always the same i.e. it seems to correctly execute a certain number of commands that are being successfully queried against the database, then failing.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I should also note that this utility is exhibiting this behavior across 4 different production servers each with their own dedicated local database server, and that these are beefy machines with 8-16 GB RAM each that are managed by a professional sysadmin.

Comment: AFAIK, no. Sounds like a utility logic problem.

Comment: It's possible for SQL Server to update a row where there are effectively no changes in the data. For example, setting a column value equal to its current value. Triggers on the table can also affect how many rows were modified.

Comment: How/where are you checking @@ROWCOUNT? You can run profiler to see if there are any statements issued between the update command and the check for @@ROWCOUNT (including those that might come from a trigger, or the program sending the update command...). The fact that it happens across multiple servers definitely adds weight to the "logic problem" argument.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: may not be @@ROWCOUNT in a client language eg SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: @gbn sure, but my point is the same - it could still be getting the wrong count because of another command that slipped in between.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: true, as I noted in my answer. I *should have* said that OP shouldn't look for explicitly @@ROWCOUNT because it my not be used

Comment: @gbn yep, I just meant that as the count he's checking, not @@ROWCOUNT explicitly.

Comment: @gbn The commands are being executed from C# using ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: In your use of ExecuteNonQuery, are you noticing if it ever returns -1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on what you say...

It is possible for the "xx rows affected" to be misleading if you have a trigger firing. You may be reading the count from the trigger. If so, add SET NOCOUNT ON to the trigger

Alternatively, the data is the same, so you actually do dummy update with the same values. Add a WHERE clause to test for differences for example.

Comment: Our database administrator says there are no database triggers in our servers, and I've just double-checked so that can't be it. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @user808532: well, I'd consider your logic/utility is wrong then. Dont waste time looking for a SQL Server cuplprit

Answer (score 4):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE MyTable
SET Message = ''
WHERE ID = 2

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Messages:

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: Awesome, learn something new everyday. Unfortunately I just looked through the 700,000+ command file and none of them have rollbacks, so this can't be it.

Comment: "I just need to know of it's THEORETICALLY possible for SQL server to report that at least one row was affected and yet no apply the change."  Question answered.  If you want the answer to a different question, you have to ask that question.

Comment: I tell you're a programmer with that airtight logic. I guess I should clarify the bounds of my question: all commands are INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or ALTER TABLE in this particular file.